# replace the "full name" key with abbreviation key in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries.

```
# {state full name: elevation}
elevation = {'Mississippi': 300.0, 'Oklahoma': 1300.0, 'Wyoming': 6700.0, 'Minnesota': 1200.0, 'Illinois': 600.0, 'Arkansas': 650.0, 'New Mexico': 5700.0, 'Ohio': 850.0, 'Indiana': 700.0, 'Maryland': 350.0, 'Louisiana': 100.0, 'Texas': 1700.0, 'Tennessee': 900.0, 'Arizona': 4100.0, 'Iowa': 1100.0, 'Michigan': 900.0, 'Kansas': 2000.0, 'Utah': 6100.0, 'Virginia': 950.0, 'Oregon': 3300.0, 'Connecticut': 500.0, 'Montana': 3400.0, 'California': 2900.0, 'Idaho': 5000.0, 'West Virginia': 1500.0, 'South Carolina': 350.0, 'New Hampshire': 1000.0, 'Massachusetts': 500.0, 'Vermont': 1000.0, 'Georgia': 600.0, 'North Dakota': 1900.0, 'Pennsylvania': 1100.0, 'Florida': 100.0, 'Hawaii': 3030.0, 'Kentucky': 750.0, 'Alaska': 1900.0, 'Nebraska': 2600.0, 'Missouri': 800.0, 'Wisconsin': 1050.0, 'Alabama': 500.0, 'Rhode Island': 200.0, 'South Dakota': 2200.0, 'Colorado': 6800.0, 'New Jersey': 250.0, 'Washington': 1700.0, 'North Carolina': 700.0, 'New York': 1000.0, 'Nevada': 5500.0, 'Delaware': 60.0, 'Maine': 600.0}

# {abbreviation:full name}
postal = {'WA': 'WASHINGTON', 'VA': 'VIRGINIA', 'DE': 'DELAWARE', 'DC': 'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA', 'WI': 'WISCONSIN', 'WV': 'WEST VIRGINIA', 'HI': 'HAWAII', 'FL': 'FLORIDA', 'FM': 'FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA', 'WY': 'WYOMING', 'NH': 'NEW HAMPSHIRE', 'NJ': 'NEW JERSEY', 'NM': 'NEW MEXICO', 'TX': 'TEXAS', 'LA': 'LOUISIANA', 'NC': 'NORTH CAROLINA', 'ND': 'NORTH DAKOTA', 'NE': 'NEBRASKA', 'TN': 'TENNESSEE', 'NY': 'NEW YORK', 'PA': 'PENNSYLVANIA', 'CA': 'CALIFORNIA', 'NV': 'NEVADA', 'PW': 'PALAU', 'GU': 'GUAM GU', 'CO': 'COLORADO', 'VI': 'VIRGIN ISLANDS', 'AK': 'ALASKA', 'AL': 'ALABAMA', 'AS': 'AMERICAN SAMOA', 'AR': 'ARKANSAS', 'VT': 'VERMONT', 'IL': 'ILLINOIS', 'GA': 'GEORGIA', 'IN': 'INDIANA', 'IA': 'IOWA', 'OK': 'OKLAHOMA', 'AZ': 'ARIZONA', 'ID': 'IDAHO', 'CT': 'CONNECTICUT', 'ME': 'MAINE', 'MD': 'MARYLAND', 'MA': 'MASSACHUSETTS', 'OH': 'OHIO', 'UT': 'UTAH', 'MO': 'MISSOURI', 'MN': 'MINNESOTA', 'MI': 'MICHIGAN', 'MH': 'MARSHALL ISLANDS', 'RI': 'RHODE ISLAND', 'KS': 'KANSAS', 'MT': 'MONTANA', 'MP': 'NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS', 'MS': 'MISSISSIPPI', 'PR': 'PUERTO RICO', 'SC': 'SOUTH CAROLINA', 'KY': 'KENTUCKY', 'OR': 'OREGON', 'SD': 'SOUTH DAKOTA'}
```

**I want to make a new dic so it takes the {abbreviation:elevation}**, and the key in the new dict must be in both "elevation" and "postal", something like:

```
{'MS': 300.0, 'OK': 1300.0, 'WY': 6700.0, 'MN': 1200.0, ....}
```

I write the function:

```
def rekeyDict(dct,mapping):
    newDict = {}
    for key in dct.keys():
        try:
            newDict[mapping[key.upper()]] = dct[key]
        except Exception, error:
            print "failed",error
            pass
    return newDict

elevation = rekeyDict(elevation,postal)
print elevation
```

however, it gives me a blank dic. How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work fine for you, just one line different. You should just exchange the key and value of your mapping dict.

```
def rekeyDict(dct,mapping):
    newDict = {}
    # below is different line
    mapping = {v:k for k, v in mapping.items()}
    for key in dct:
        try:
            newDict[mapping[key.upper()]] = dct[key]
        except Exception, error:
            print "failed",error
            pass
    return newDict

elevation = rekeyDict(elevation,postal)
print elevation
```

Answer (score 3):

```
elevation = {'Mississippi': 300.0, 'Oklahoma': 1300.0, 'Wyoming': 6700.0, 'Minnesota': 1200.0, 'Illinois': 600.0, 'Arkansas': 650.0, 'New Mexico': 5700.0, 'Ohio': 850.0, 'Indiana': 700.0, 'Maryland': 350.0, 'Louisiana': 100.0, 'Texas': 1700.0, 'Tennessee': 900.0, 'Arizona': 4100.0, 'Iowa': 1100.0, 'Michigan': 900.0, 'Kansas': 2000.0, 'Utah': 6100.0, 'Virginia': 950.0, 'Oregon': 3300.0, 'Connecticut': 500.0, 'Montana': 3400.0, 'California': 2900.0, 'Idaho': 5000.0, 'West Virginia': 1500.0, 'South Carolina': 350.0, 'New Hampshire': 1000.0, 'Massachusetts': 500.0, 'Vermont': 1000.0, 'Georgia': 600.0, 'North Dakota': 1900.0, 'Pennsylvania': 1100.0, 'Florida': 100.0, 'Hawaii': 3030.0, 'Kentucky': 750.0, 'Alaska': 1900.0, 'Nebraska': 2600.0, 'Missouri': 800.0, 'Wisconsin': 1050.0, 'Alabama': 500.0, 'Rhode Island': 200.0, 'South Dakota': 2200.0, 'Colorado': 6800.0, 'New Jersey': 250.0, 'Washington': 1700.0, 'North Carolina': 700.0, 'New York': 1000.0, 'Nevada': 5500.0, 'Delaware': 60.0, 'Maine': 600.0}
postal = {'WA': 'WASHINGTON', 'VA': 'VIRGINIA', 'DE': 'DELAWARE', 'DC': 'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA', 'WI': 'WISCONSIN', 'WV': 'WEST VIRGINIA', 'HI': 'HAWAII', 'FL': 'FLORIDA', 'FM': 'FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA', 'WY': 'WYOMING', 'NH': 'NEW HAMPSHIRE', 'NJ': 'NEW JERSEY', 'NM': 'NEW MEXICO', 'TX': 'TEXAS', 'LA': 'LOUISIANA', 'NC': 'NORTH CAROLINA', 'ND': 'NORTH DAKOTA', 'NE': 'NEBRASKA', 'TN': 'TENNESSEE', 'NY': 'NEW YORK', 'PA': 'PENNSYLVANIA', 'CA': 'CALIFORNIA', 'NV': 'NEVADA', 'PW': 'PALAU', 'GU': 'GUAM GU', 'CO': 'COLORADO', 'VI': 'VIRGIN ISLANDS', 'AK': 'ALASKA', 'AL': 'ALABAMA', 'AS': 'AMERICAN SAMOA', 'AR': 'ARKANSAS', 'VT': 'VERMONT', 'IL': 'ILLINOIS', 'GA': 'GEORGIA', 'IN': 'INDIANA', 'IA': 'IOWA', 'OK': 'OKLAHOMA', 'AZ': 'ARIZONA', 'ID': 'IDAHO', 'CT': 'CONNECTICUT', 'ME': 'MAINE', 'MD': 'MARYLAND', 'MA': 'MASSACHUSETTS', 'OH': 'OHIO', 'UT': 'UTAH', 'MO': 'MISSOURI', 'MN': 'MINNESOTA', 'MI': 'MICHIGAN', 'MH': 'MARSHALL ISLANDS', 'RI': 'RHODE ISLAND', 'KS': 'KANSAS', 'MT': 'MONTANA', 'MP': 'NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS', 'MS': 'MISSISSIPPI', 'PR': 'PUERTO RICO', 'SC': 'SOUTH CAROLINA', 'KY': 'KENTUCKY', 'OR': 'OREGON', 'SD': 'SOUTH DAKOTA'}

newDict = {}
for key, value in postal.iteritems():
    newDict[key] = elevation.get(value.title())
```

**Output:**

```
{'AK': 1900.0, 'AL': 500.0, 'AR': 650.0, 'AS': None, 'AZ': 4100.0, 'CA': 2900.0, 'CO': 6800.0, 'CT': 500.0, 'DC': None, 'DE': 60.0, 'FL': 100.0, 'FM': None, 'GA': 600.0, 'GU': None, 'HI': 3030.0, 'IA': 1100.0, 'ID': 5000.0, 'IL': 600.0, 'IN': 700.0, 'KS': 2000.0, 'KY': 750.0, 'LA': 100.0, 'MA': 500.0, 'MD': 350.0, 'ME': 600.0,'MH': None, 'MI': 900.0, 'MN': 1200.0, 'MO': 800.0, 'MP': None, 'MS': 300.0, 'MT': 3400.0, 'NC': 700.0, 'ND': 1900.0, 'NE': 2600.0, 'NH': 1000.0, 'NJ': 250.0, 'NM': 5700.0, 'NV': 5500.0, 'NY': 1000.0, 'OH': 850.0, 'OK': 1300.0, 'OR': 3300.0, 'PA': 1100.0, 'PR': None, 'PW': None, 'RI': 200.0, 'SC': 350.0, 'SD': 2200.0, 'TN': 900.0, 'TX': 1700.0, 'UT': 6100.0, 'VA': 950.0, 'VI': None, 'VT': 1000.0, 'WA': 1700.0, 'WI': 1050.0, 'WV': 1500.0, 'WY': 6700.0}
```

Comment: Note that postal and elevation have different lenghts, this will return KeyError,

Comment: IMHO, that is no reason for a downvote, but a comment pointing it. Anyway, your solution looks better for me, much less code (Zen of Python, http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: I undid my downvote after your edit, don't want to be mean :) but really you should check your code, are you sure it produces correct output here?

Comment: @Pawelmhm Yeah. I checked in the terminator. It does.

Comment: @Pawelmhm I have made the correction. Got my mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`mapping[key.upper()]` doesn't work, because postal is a map of abreviations to names, not the other way around. It's easier if you think of replacing the values rather than the keys:

```
def reValueDict(keydict, valuedict):
    newDict = {}
    for key, value in keydict.iteritems():
        newDict[key] = valuedict.get(value.title())
    return newDict

print reValueDict(postal, elevation)
```

Note that I've had to replace `.upper()` with `.title()` to do the inverse mapping

Or as a one-liner:

```
print {k: elevation.get(v.title()) for k, v in postal.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your task will be much easier if you change your dictionary so that it maps full state names to short ones. You can also use dictionary `get` method to avoid getting KeyErrors each time there is no key for a state.

```
def reKey(elevation, postal):
    newDict = {}

    # creating new postal dict here
    # you will have something like {"SOUTH CAROLINA": "SC",..}
    newPostal = dict(zip(postal.values(),postal.keys()))
    for key in elevation:
        value = elevation[key]
        # dict.get allows you to avoid try except block
        # if there is no key it returns None
        # also you now have state full names as keys in newPostal
        # so you can just capitalize keys to elevate to get keys to newPostal
        newKey = newPostal.get(key.upper(),None)
        if newKey:
            newDict[newKey] = value
    return newDict

print reKey(elevation, postal)
```